# How do I retrieve data in Monday to Friday Hourly Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that is currently in the following format

| ID | Title | CreatedOn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test 1 | 2021-04-26 08:00:00 |
| 2 | Test 2 | 2021-04-26 10:00:00 |
| 3 | Test 3 | 2021-04-27 09:00:00 |
| 4 | Test 4 | 2021-04-28 14:00:00 |
| 5 | Test 5 | 2021-04-28 16:00:00 |
| 6 | Test 6 | 2021-04-28 12:00:00 |
| 7 | Test 7 | 2021-04-29 13:00:00 |
| 8 | Test 8 | 2021-04-30 06:00:00 |
| 9 | Test 9 | 2021-05-17 10:00:00 |
| 10 | Test 10 | 2021-05-18 19:00:00 |
| 11 | Test 11 | 2021-05-18 23:00:00 |
| 12 | Test 12 | 2021-05-19 16:00:00 |
| 13 | Test 13 | 2021-05-20 07:00:00 |
| 14 | Test 14 | 2021-05-21 14:00:00 |
| 15 | Test 15 | 2021-05-21 10:00:00 |
| 16 | Test 16 | 2021-04-30 10:00:00 |

What I would like to do is a query that would tell me how many requests have been Monday to Friday per hour. So aggregate all the data into just rows of Monday to Friday.

So the query should return

| Day | Hour | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | 08:00 | 1 |
| Monday | 10:00 | 2 |
| Tuesday | 10:00 | 1 |
| Tuesday | 19:00 | 1 |
| Tuesday | 23:00 | 1 |
| Wednesday | 14:00 | 1 |
| Wednesday | 16:00 | 2 |
| Wednesday | 12:00 | 1 |

etc.. How do I achieve this?

So far I have the following

```
SELECT
  DATENAME(WEEK, CreatedOn) AS Week,
  DATEPART(Hour, CreatedOn) AS Hour,
  COUNT(*) AS Requests
FROM [Enterprise32].[dbo].[nav_EmailEstimateRequests]
where CreatedOn > '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY DATENAME(WK, CreatedOn),DATEPART(Hour, CreatedOn)
ORDER BY DATENAME(WK, CreatedOn);
```

But the above query returns each week so Week 1 up until Week 21. Please guide me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `weekday` for the date part:

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CreatedOn) AS Weekday,
       DATEPART(Hour, CreatedOn) AS Hour,
       COUNT(*) AS Requests
FROM [Enterprise32].[dbo].[nav_EmailEstimateRequests]
WHERE CreatedOn > '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CreatedOn), DATEPART(Hour, CreatedOn), DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CreatedOn)
ORDER BY DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CreatedOn), Hour;
```

Note:  I included `DATEPART(weekday, )` in the `GROUP BY`, so you could use it in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thank you, I was so close! Not a SQL expert, trying to learn on the job. This is exactly what I was looking for.